# pip install --upgrade exclude a list of files from being overwritten

Tags: python, pip

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of solving an issue. We have a python package, which comes with some config files, that are being populated after the first time setup. We are installing the upgrade on the customer's machine via `pip install --upgrade git+...` which works very well.

However, we would like to exclude/preserve some of the files. Currently, we are preserving it, by copying/installing/pasting it.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you automate the copy/install/paste process in a script?

Comment: As described in the thread, that's what we are doing at the moment, by `copying/installing/pasting` I've meant automated

Comment: You shouldn’t change what works!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as far as I know, at least not without complicated and unnecessary work. Your configuration files just do not belong in the locations where Python projects are installed.

If possible:

- either ask the user where they want the configuration files to be saved;
- or use one of the commonly accepted standard locations, for example [*`platformdirs`*](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) can help with that;
- a combination of both is the obvious best choice, ask the user first and fall back to a standard location as default.